# ManifestStaticFilesStorage - still fetching old static file even when staticfiles.json shows the right mapping

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-storage, django-static

I am using using ManifestStaticFilesStorage. After performing `collectstatic` and moving over the files to prod, I still see old css file (with old MD5 hash string) being fetched.

settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

On prod, I can see staticfiles.json showing the correct (new) css file but still when I do 'view-source' from the web page, I can see old css being fetched.

What could I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restart Django on prod after moving the files over.

(I don't know why that's required but thats the only thing that works)

Update (Aug 2022): I ran into the same problem after 5 years and bumped into my own post. This time restarting Django also did not help. But restarting Nginx helped (got the hint from @patrickm96's answer) - in case it helps

Comment: I't because django caches content of the staticfiles.json file in memory during startup. It's used for quick lookup for hashed file name for every static file  in `{% static %}` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and restarting gunicorn helped me